# How to get the groups in the "Member of" tab in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

My first project is to create a web tool for our Active Directory. One of the things I need to do is get and display the Groups displayed in "MemberOf" tab of a user account in Active Directory and pass it to a gridview. I've done some home work and here is what I have.

I have a textbox (txtusername) and right beside it is a button ("Search Groups of this User").

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ADMAM.GetUserGroups(txtusername.Text, Session["WindowsID"].ToString(), Session["Password"].ToString());
}

public DataTable GetUserGroups(string sUserName, string windowsid, string password)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = GetUser(sUserName, windowsid, password);

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> oPrincipalSearchResult = oUserPrincipal.GetGroups();

    foreach (Principal oResult in oPrincipalSearchResult)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(oResult.Name);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

I still can't get the groups inside the tab of "MemberOf".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `.GetAuthorizationGroups` call:

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> oPrincipalSearchResult = oUserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();

foreach (Principal oResult in oPrincipalSearchResult)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(oResult.Name);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

This has the added benefit that it will recursively search through group memberships for a user (if the user is member of `Group A` which in turn is member of `Group B`, then `.GetAuthorizationGroups()` will also return `Group B` as a group the user is a member of - indirectly).

Comment: Hi marc_s

Thanks for the professional advice. I tried your advise... However, still i was unable to get the groups inside the memberof tab.

Vice Versa, I am able to get the members of an OU. My goal is to get the memberships a user belongs to. I tried searching my account which is a memberof 8-10 groups. but none of them appeared on my query. Is there anything i overlooked or misused (probably there is)?

Thanks for the reply! Appreciate it much!